# Двойные шрифты в iphone

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, iphone, шрифты

[image: Вот такая вот штука]

Подключение шрифта

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'helveticaneuecyrthin';
  src: url('HelveticaNeueCyr-Thin.eot?') format('eot'), url('HelveticaNeueCyr-Thin.ttf') format("truetype"), url('HelveticaNeueCyr-Thin.otf') format("opentype");
}
```

Используется **HelveticaNeueCyr-Thin**.

Применение шрифта

```
h2 {
  font-family: "helveticaneuecyrthin";
}
```

На андроиде и на компьютере шрифт отображается корректно. Такая ошибка встречается только на **iphone**

Подскажите что можно с этим сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Решение

```
h2 {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue Cyr Thin", "helveticaneuecyrthin";
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

задать отдельный стиль в css для iphone, посмотреть можно [тут](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPhone)
или через js, где будем добавлять класс `.mac-os` в body

```
<script>
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mac') > 0)
    $('body').addClass('mac-os');
</script>
```

после чего в css правка для мака будет 
`body.mac-os h2 {margin-left:-3px;}`
как вариант

Comment: Не помогло. На iphone всё ещё осталась проблема

Comment: @GoodWin332, воспользуйтесь ссылкой http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPhone , там есть все возможные варианты, каждый из них точно работает.